# What's the sign of $\det\phi'=\pm 1$ where $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a permutation of coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, permutations

Let $S_n$ denote the [symmetric group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) and $$\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto\left(\begin{array}{c}x_{\pi(1)}\\\vdots\\x_{\pi(n)}\end{array}\right)$$ for some $\pi\in S_n$. Obviously, $$\phi'=\left(\begin{array}{c}e_{\pi(1)}\\\vdots\\e_{\pi(n)}\end{array}\right)$$ where $e_i$ denotes the unit row vector. The idea is now to swap the elements of the matrix and use basic facts about the determinant, e.g. $$\det\phi'\;\stackrel{\text{swap rows }1\text{ and }\xi_1}{=}\;(-1)^{\min(\xi_1-1,1)}\left|\begin{array}{c}e_1\\\vdots\\e_{\pi_1}\\\vdots\\e_{\pi(n)}\end{array}\right|$$ where $\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n\in\left\{1,\ldots,\right\}$ can be chosen such that $\pi(\xi_i)=i$.

However, how can we deal with [inversions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Inversions) and get the correct sign of $\det\phi'=\pm 1$?

Answer (score 2):

The sign of the determinant is $+1$ for an even permutation and $-1$ for an odd permutation.

To see this, factor the permutation as a product of transposition $i \leftrightarrow j$. It does not matter whether $i$ equals $1$ or something else. This factorization of the permutation corresponds directly to factoring the matrix as a composition of row swaps. So the number of row swaps equals the number of transpositions which is either even or odd, and that is the meaning of an even or odd permutation. Since a row swap changes the determinant by $-1$, it follows that the sign of the determinant is $+1$ for an even permutation and $-1$ for an odd permutation.